# Plagiarism Checker C# based API

Tags: api

I am looking for a plagiarism checker API that is based on C# code. I need to use it on my web service. I need to easily query plagiarism checking engine and get result for the originality of the text.

If you know any service that is similar to what I am asking it would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m using an online plagiarism checker service called [Copyleaks](http://copyleaks.com) which offers an interface to integrate with their API (HTTP REST). It also provides interface which is fully compatible with C#.

Steps to integrate with Copyleaks API:

1. Register on Copyleaks website.
2. Create a new C# Console application project and install [Copyleaks’ Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CopyleaksAPI/).
3. Use the following code which performs a webpage scan.

This code was taken from its SDK ([GitHub](https://github.com/Copyleaks/API)):

```
public void Scan(string username, string apiKey, string url)
{
    // Login to Copyleaks server.
    Console.Write("User login... ");
    LoginToken token = UsersAuthentication.Login(username, apiKey);
    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\tSuccess!");

    // Create a new process on server.
    Console.Write("Submiting new request... ");
    Detector detector = new Detector(token);
    ScannerProcess process = detector.CreateProcess(url);
    Console.WriteLine("\tSuccess!");

    // Waiting to process to be finished.
    Console.Write("Waiting for completion... ");
    while (!process.IsCompleted())
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Console.WriteLine("\tSuccess!");

    // Getting results.
    Console.Write("Getting results... ");
    var results = process.GetResults();
    if (results.Length == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\tNo results.");
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Result {0}:", i + 1);
            Console.WriteLine("Domain: {0}", results[i].Domain);
            Console.WriteLine("Url: {0}", results[i].URL);
            Console.WriteLine("Precents: {0}", results[i].Precents);
            Console.WriteLine("CopiedWords: {0}", results[i].NumberOfCopiedWords);
        }
    }
}
```

Call the function with your Username, API-Key and the URL of the content you wish to scan for plagiarism.

You can read more about its server in ["How To" tutorial](https://api.copyleaks.com/Guides/HowToUse).